SwiftUI ScrollView animations: How to automatic scroll and ease out properly?
I'm implementing a horizontal scrollview of full-screen images of paintings that I want to autoscroll on appear.
At the end of the animation, it's supposed to scroll in an easeOut fashion, but it abruptly stops like a normal animation despite me using easeOut. any tips?
.onAppear {
                    // TODO: lmfao
                    // Scroll a bit to the next image
                    if enableAutoscrollShenanigans {
                        
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                            withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 4.0)) {
                                proxy.scrollTo(0, anchor: .center)
                            }
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                                withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 4.0)) {
                                    proxy.scrollTo(0, anchor: .trailing)
                                }
                                
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 4.0)) {
                                        proxy.scrollTo(1, anchor: .leading)
                                        
                                        // self.startautomaticscrolling = true
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }


You might be able to use a PhaseAnimator for this. See also How to infinitely loop and move image in swiftUI in intervals?

Unfortunately you can't use DispatchQueue in View structs because they have no lifetime. If you want a longer lifetime you need to either use .task or the old @StateObject.

So a few things I want to point out, if you're using .onAppear on a parent view of a ScrollView you can end up with unexpected outcomes. You can't guarantee whether a view will appear when you expect it to. Secondly, you're using a DispatchQueue to control when particular animations should happen, and that's not ideal. So here's a proposed revision that "May" fix the issue. I don't have an IDE available right now, so bear with me.
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView { // Horizontal or Vertical
        // Some ForEach or List of Views
        YourCustomViewA
            .animation(.easeInOut)
            .onAppear {
                proxy.scrollTo(selectedViewId)
            }
    }
}

Doing it this way you guarantee that the scrolling behavior only happens when the particular view is on the hierarchy. The documentation explicitly states not to do it during ViewBuilder execution, which I believe includes the parentView.onAppear however moving it to the child should alleviate that. You should also be able to directly use .animation(...) on that same child view.
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader
